# glfw does not open the window

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw

When I am start the program, an empty console opens instead of the black screen. the error occurs when
the window is created "window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);".  the code is taken from the glfw documentation, there are no errors in it.

glfw installed with command " git clone https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git external/glfw/ "

main.cpp

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
        if (!window)
        {
            glfwTerminate();
            return -1;
        }
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        {
            //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
        glfwTerminate();
        return 0;
    }
```

CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13 FATAL_ERROR)
set(PROJECT_NAME myapp)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_INSTALL OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
add_subdirectory(external/glfw)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} OpenGL::GL)
```

in terminal

```
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

system

```
Windows 10
nvidia gtx 1060
Visual studio 2019
cmake 3.20
```

everything is updated to the latest versions

Comment: Why do you expect a black screen/window?  What happens if you uncomment the `glClear` call?

Comment: Are you sure `glfwInit` succeeds? I recommend setting up an error callback.

Comment: when debugging the program, glfwinit() works, but when it reaches the line of creating a window, debugging simply stops without displaying an error.

Comment: Did you set up an error callback?

Comment: I can confirm that this code works on Linux, yet I installed glfw without using `external/glfw`.